# unable to run a working war file in eclipse tomcat on another machine

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, war

I've a java web app that was written and executed in my friend's system, later there were some changes to be done in it, I've told him to export that file with libraries in a `war` format, When i imported and ran the same, there is nothing happening to my surprise.

There are basically 2 buttons, button is initially in active and button 2 is in a disabled state.

When i hit the first button, there is some data that is fetched from data base and it fills the textboxes and the first button is disabled here and the second gets activated.

On clicking the second button, the data that is fetched is updated in another table with somemore data and the first button gets enabled, disabling the second.

This is iterated till all the rows in database are over.

In my friend's system, it is working correctly, and in my system when i tried to import and run the same, there is no data getting fetched or getting posted, just the two buttons are fine, i mean the toggling between them.

The code is written entirely in my friend's system and in his system everything is fine, but in mine there is nothing happening.

Both of us use the same configurations, Java, eclipse and tomcat are 32 bit .

Please let me know how can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: You have described the applications function but not its architecture. Impossible to troubleshoot without further information. To that end could i suggest looking into the tomcat log files and hoping the application itself is also logging. This is where you need to start, presumably a stacktrace will be recorded somewhere that will tell you where something has gone wrong within the code, that will enable you to narrow down the root cause.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor thanks for the tip, I'll follow that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 your program runs on both machines (you can hit buttons)

2 then check the database, the connection (use an ip adress ?), name and password to connect it ? Do you export the datas ? where is the database ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I've tried updating my code with latest path (I mean, path in my system)